# How to get the record count on hourly basis unix?

Tags: shell, unix

I have thousands of files on my unix server and i want to count the records of files on hourly basis in below format. What is the easiest way to do it?

```
Date       Hour records

2022-07-08 00   5565

2022-07-08 01   77878

2022-07-08 02   545

.

.

2022-07-08 23   656

2022-07-09 00   787

2022-07-09 01   54547
```

Answer (score 1):

### Counting (recursively) all files in current dir, by hour

`find` is **the** command to use for finding filesystem entries regarding any kind of consideration. This way will print one date, limited by hour, for each **file** found.

```
find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

Output could look like:

```
    851 2022-07-13 00
    849 2022-07-13 01
    855 2022-07-13 02
    858 2022-07-13 03
...
```

#### Some cosmetic, using `sed`:

```
find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH\n' |
    sort |
    uniq -c |
    sed 's/^\( *[0-9]\+\) \([0-9-]\+\) \([0-9]\+\)/    \2  \3  \1/;
         1i\    Date        Hour  Count'
```

Will produce:

```
    Date        Hour  Count
...
    2022-07-13  00      851
    2022-07-13  01      849
    2022-07-13  02      855
    2022-07-13  03      858
...
```

#### By using `ls` instead of `find`?

Without recursivity!

```
ls -ARlrt  --time-style="+|%Y-%m-%d:%H|" |
    grep -a ^-|
    cut -d \| -f 2 |
    sort |
    uniq -c
```

Will produce near same result:

```
...
    851 2022-07-13:00
    849 2022-07-13:01
    855 2022-07-13:02
    858 2022-07-13:03
...
```

But as `ls` will print filenames who could contain *special characters*, could force `grep` to procuce wrong output... This way is not recommended!